# How do you make a clickable sprite in SFML?

Tags: c++, button, sprite, sfml, clickable

I've been looking through the SFML documentation for making clickable sprites, but so far I haven't found anything. 
Do you guys think you could help me out?

Comment: There is **nothing** like `sf::ClickableSprite` in SFML so far, and probably there will never be - [Current list of classes in SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/annotated.php). However, you can have obtain this behavior with the `sf::Sprite` object and the events. The idea is simple - as soon as you get the `sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)` event, check if the mouse is in the sprite. If it is, perform the action. You can perform another action (maybe *undo*) when button is released.

[Mouse class](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Mouse.php)

Comment: So how would I go about checking if the mouse is in the sprite?

Comment: There is [sf::Sprite::getGlobalBounds()](http://goo.gl/NQp0ne) function which returns you the position and the dimensions of the sprite. There's also [sf::Mouse::getPosition()](http://goo.gl/f5BJIz) function, which returns the current position of the mouse. Just check if the mouse has bigger x than sprite's X position and less than sprite's position+width.

Comment: `if(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x > sprite.getGlobalBounds().left && sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x < (sprite.getGlobalBounds().left + sprite.getGlobalBounds().width && sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y > sprite.getGlobalBounds().top && sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y < (sprite.getGlobalBounds().top + sprite.getGlobalBounds().height))
doAction();`

Comment: Two notes on the above: (1) If you're using views, you'll need to add the view's position to `sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)`, since it gets the mouse position relative to window coordinates; and (2) you can just use `sprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(mousePos)` (which probably just does the same thing behind the scenes).

Comment: @Chaosed0: Yes, you're right. Totally forgot about this one. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is **nothing** like `sf::ClickableSprite` in SFML so far, and probably there will never be. ([Current list of classes in SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/annotated.php))

However, you can obtain this behavior with the `sf::Sprite` object and the events. The idea is simple - as soon as you get the `sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)` event, check if the mouse is in the sprite. If it is, perform the action. You can perform another action (maybe *undo*) when button is released.

There is [sf::Sprite::getGlobalBounds()](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a203d2d8087bfdca2ebc3c0485cdb7409) function which returns you the position and the dimensions of the sprite. There's also [sf::Mouse::getPosition()](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Mouse.php#a93b4d2ebef728e77a0ec9d83c1e0b0c8) function, which returns the current position of the mouse. **You can use `sprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(mousePos)` to check whether the mouse is in the sprite.**

If you're using views, you'll need to add the view's position to `sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)`, since it gets the mouse position relative to window coordinates.

(thanks to [Chaosed0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110292/chaosed0) for additional notes.)